# Why are these 2 date commands giving different results?

Tags: date

```
$ date -d "Apr 1 2016 - 1 month" +%B
```

gives me "March", which is great - the month that comes before April is March.
If I do this however:

```
$ date -d "$(date -d "Apr 1 2016") - 1 month" +%B
```

it gives me "February". This is causing a bug in some more complex code I have. Why are these 2 commands showing different results?

Comment: Both gave me `March`

Comment: As explained by Thomas, this is dependent upon your timezone. My DST changes on March 13th - yours probably does not, so you may not see this behavior on the same dates, or possibly at all if you have no DST changes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can see the problem by turning on the shell trace:

```
+ date -d 'Apr 1 2016 - 1 month' +%B
March
++ date -d 'Apr 1 2016'
+ date -d 'Fri Apr  1 00:00:00 EDT 2016 - 1 month' +%B
February
```

When you use the output of the inner `date` command, it is at the very beginning of April, and when subtracting a month runs into the discontinuity due to EST/EDT changing:

```
+ date -d 'Fri Apr  1 00:00:00 EDT 2016 - 1 month'
Mon Feb 29 23:00:00 EST 2016
```

Your results, of course, will vary according to your local timezone settings.  Turning on the trace will show the timezone (in my case, `EDT`).

The reason why the results differ is that in the latter case you have given more information to `date`, made its parameter more *specific*, i.e., the specific time of day.  In the first part, that was not specified, giving `date` more leeway about how to determine the date/time to display.

Comment: I now realize that this has to do with the daylight savings time (mine are here: http://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/canada/edmonton), but I'm still not following why the date command appears to be interpreting the same date differently in a subshell than in the main shell. If I run a script with: `date -d "Apr 1 2016"; date -d "$(date -d "Apr 1 2016")"`, I get exactly the same result, including the same timezone tag - why is removing a month from both giving different results?

Comment: Oh - your last edit makes it clear. Thanks